# What gas is evolved when using vinegar, hydrogen peroxide, and salt to etch copper, and why?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

The question of how vinegar + hydrogen peroxide + table salt can be used to etch copper has been asked before ([Full equation when using vinegar, hydrogen peroxide, and salt to etch copper](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102156/full-equation-when-using-vinegar-hydrogen-peroxide-and-salt-to-etch-copper)). However, the accepted answer seems to miss a key fact when observing this reaction, so I wanted to ask for clarification in the hope that someone can explain the unaddressed fact.

When the vinegar + hydrogen peroxide + table salt solution is used to etch copper, there is a gas that vigorously forms on the surface being etched. However, none of the reaction products in the accepted answer for the full equation for this reaction are volatile. So if none of the reaction products are volatile, how can a gas be released?  Clearly, there is something missing from the accepted answer. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Make a bold guess! ;)

Comment: My guess would be hydrogen, but if so, the accepted equation for this reaction is wrong, so I am hoping someone can address both points at once.

Comment: OK, it´s not hydrogen. Hydrogen evolves when *base* metals react with water (or acid). Next guess, please. (The accepted answer of that other question is correct as far as I see, but it does in fact not tell you what gas comes out. There is another reaction.)

Comment: OK, so it is probably oxygen, then. So what is the missing link in the reaction process?

Comment: Correct. The point is that you add a rather large excess of peroxide. It just bubbles away.

Comment: So it is just direct decomposition of H2O2?  Why does it happen only at the copper surface?  I have been using this chemistry to etch PC boards, and the bubbles form very vigorously at the Cu surface, but hardly at all in the masked areas, or on the surface of the tank.

Comment: Well, the Cu surface is probably the most coarse of all, and then it´s somewhat catalytic. Why exactly? Tried if other metals do the same?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful discussion. I'll have to see what happens with other metals...